# Fedex Freight API not giving accurate rates

Tags: php

The code the developer put in our site has a bunch of express (non freight) service types.  I only need to implement FedEx Freight rates into my website and the developer has ran off on me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
if($cominfo[0]['companyNAME'] == "FedEx" && $rescar12[0]['login']!="" && $rescar12[0]['carpassword']!="" && $rescar12[0]['accountNUMBER']!="" && $rescar12[0]['accesskey']!="" && $rescar12[0]['meterkey']!=""){

        /*$fedx_accountnumber = $rescar12[0]['accountNUMBER'];
        $fedex_meterkey = $rescar12[0]['meterkey'];
        $fedex_freightAccount = $rescar12[0]['meterkey'];
        $fedex_accessKey = $rescar12[0]['meterkey'];
        $fedex_productionPassword = $rescar12[0]['meterkey'];*/
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_SESSION['order']);
        $fedx_accountnumber = 'account number';
        $fedex_meterkey = 'meter key';
        $fedex_freightAccount = 'freight account';
        $fedex_accessKey = 'secret access key';
        $fedex_productionPassword = 'secret password';


        //$services1['fedex']['STANDARDOVERNIGHT'] = 'Standard Overnight';
        if($_SESSION['order'][$counter]['weight_unit'] != "lb"){
          $weight= convert_weight($_SESSION['order'][$counter]['weight'],$_SESSION['order'][$counter]['weight_unit'],'lb');
          $weight_units =  'LB';
        } else{
           $weight = $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['weight'] ;
           $weight_units =  $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['weight_unit'];
        }

        // Services
            $services = $services1;
            // Weight
            $weight = $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['weight']; // Default = 1 
            $weight_units =  $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['weight_unit']; // lb (default), oz, gram, kg
            // Size
            $size_length = $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['len_gth']; // Default = 8
            $size_width = $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['width']; // Default = 4
            $size_height =  $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['height']; // Default = 2
            $size_units = $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['dimesions']; // in (default), feet, cm 
            $role = $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['role'];
            // From
            $from_zip =  $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['f_zipcode'];
            $from_state = $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['f_stateID']; // Only Required for FedEx
            $from_country =  $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['f_countryID'];
            $from_city = $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['f_cityID'];
            // To
            $to_zip = $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['t_zipcode'];
            $to_state = $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['t_stateID']; // Only Required for FedEx
            $to_country = $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['t_countryID'];
            $to_city = $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['t_cityID'];


        require_once "library/fedex-common.php";
        //Please include and reference in $path_to_wsdl variable.
        $path_to_wsdl = "wsdl/RateService_v14.wsdl";

        ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

        $client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array('trace' => 1)); // Refer to http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.soap.php for more information

        $request['WebAuthenticationDetail'] = array(
            'UserCredential' =>array(
                'Key' => getProperty('key'), 
                'Password' => getProperty('password')
            )
        ); 
        $request['ClientDetail'] = array(
            'AccountNumber' => getProperty('shipaccount'), 
            'MeterNumber' => getProperty('meter')
        );
        $request['TransactionDetail'] = array('CustomerTransactionId' => ' *** Rate Request v14 using PHP ***');
        $request['Version'] = array(
            'ServiceId' => 'crs', 
            'Major' => '14', 
            'Intermediate' => '0', 
            'Minor' => '0'
        );
        $request['ReturnTransitAndCommit'] = true;
        $request['RequestedShipment']['DropoffType'] = 'REGULAR_PICKUP'; // valid values REGULAR_PICKUP, REQUEST_COURIER, ...
        $request['RequestedShipment']['ShipTimestamp'] = date('c');
        $request['RequestedShipment']['ServiceType'] = 'FEDEX_FREIGHT_ECONOMY'; // valid values STANDARD_OVERNIGHT, PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT, FEDEX_GROUND, ...
        $request['RequestedShipment']['PackagingType'] = 'YOUR_PACKAGING'; // valid values FEDEX_BOX, FEDEX_PAK, FEDEX_TUBE, YOUR_PACKAGING, ...
        $request['RequestedShipment']['Shipper'] = getProperty('freightbilling');
        $request['RequestedShipment']['Recipient'] = addRecipient();
        $request['RequestedShipment']['ShippingChargesPayment'] = addShippingChargesPayment();
        $request['RequestedShipment']['FreightShipmentDetail'] = array(
            'FedExFreightAccountNumber' => getProperty('freightaccount'),
            'FedExFreightBillingContactAndAddress' => getProperty('freightbilling'),
            'Role' =>$role,
            'PaymentType' => 'PREPAID',
            'LineItems' => array(
                'FreightClass' => 'CLASS_0'.$_SESSION['order'][$counter]['class'],
                'Weight' => array(
                    'Value' => $weight,
                    'Units' => $weight_units,
                ),
                'Dimensions' => array(
                    'Length' => $size_length,
                    'Width' => $size_width,
                    'Height' => $size_height,
                    'Units' => $size_units
                ),
            )
        );
        $request['RequestedShipment']['RateRequestTypes'] = 'ACCOUNT'; 
        $request['RequestedShipment']['RateRequestTypes'] = 'LIST'; 
        $request['RequestedShipment']['PackageCount'] = '1';



        try{

            if(setEndpoint('changeEndpoint')){
                $newLocation = $client->__setLocation(setEndpoint('endpoint'));
            }

            $response = $client -> getRates($request);
           echo '<pre>';
                print_r($response);
                exit;
            if ($response -> HighestSeverity != 'FAILURE' && $response -> HighestSeverity != 'ERROR'){      
                echo $rateReply = $response -> RateReplyDetails->RatedShipmentDetails[0]->ShipmentRateDetail->TotalNetCharge->Amount;


               // printSuccess($client, $response);
            }else{
                echo $rateReply ='N/A';
                //printError($client, $response);
            } 

            //writeToLog($client);    // Write to log file  
        } catch (SoapFault $exception) {
           printFault($exception, $client);        
        }

        $_SESSION['FedEx'][$counter]['price'] = $rateReply;

    }
```

Comment: I suggest you edit this to remove your account credentials that are now in the public domain; then get them changed for your account with FedEx

Comment: those where the non production credentials but thanks for editing for me.